# $\rho(x,y)= |e^{-x} - e^{-y}|.$ Show that $(R,\rho)$ is not complete. To this end exhibit a Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

For the second half of the part I guess $x_n=n$ could be such a sequence maybe? But I'm not sure about the first part.

Comment: In a complete metric space every Cauchy sequence convergence. So, if you have found a divergent Cauchy sequence, you have shown that the space is not complete.

Comment: So If i show that $x_n=n$ is a cauchy sequence, how do I show that that it is in $\rho$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} e^{-n} = 0$, which means that the sequence $e^{-n}$ is convergent in the reals and hence Cauchy in the usual metric.

This immediately implies that $x_n = n$ is a Cauchy sequence in the $\rho$-metric.

But if $x_n$ would converge to $p \in \mathbb{R}$ in the $\rho$-metric, then this would mean that $\rho(p, x_n)$ would tend to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity, but $\left|e^{-p} - e^{-n}\right| \rightarrow e^{-p} > 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so the sequence cannot converge to any point of the reals. So $(\mathbb{R},\rho)$ is not complete.